# Electrolysis of molten nitrates, sulphates and carbonates

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

We know that `nitrates`, `sulfates` and `carbonates` doesn't or hardly oxidized by anode in the aqueous solution.

What will be produced on anode in the electrolysis of molten salts of these ions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common theme is disproportionation of the anion, and potential reactivity with the electrodes.

---

**Nitrates**

*Electrochemical behavior of nickel electrodes in molten potassium nitrate with increased basicity*, Electrochimica Acta, Vol. 36, No. 3/4, pp. 65S-660, 1991:

> $\text{Ni}$ electrodes in a $\ce{KNO_3}$ melt [...] some ionic species of nickelite ($\ce{NiO_2^{2-}}$) and nickelate ($\ce{NiO_2^{-}}$) type

*Voltammetric investigations of the oxygen electrochemical systems in molten sodium nitrate at 420°C*, Electrochimica Acta, Vol. 33, No. 4, pp. 545-549, 1988:

> the potential range is limited anodically by the electrochemical oxidation of nitrate ions into nitrogen dioxide and oxygen: $\ce{NO3-} \to \ce{NO2} + \frac{1}{2}\ce{O2} + \ce{e-}$ and cathodically by the electrochemical reduction of nitrate ions into nitrite ions: $\ce{NO3-} + \ce{2e-} \to \ce{NO2-} + \ce{O^2-}$

**Carbonates**

*Electrochemical formation of carbon nano-powders with various porosities in molten alkali carbonates*, Electrochimica Acta, Vol. 54, pp. 4566–4573, 2009:

> reduction of carbonate ions: $\ce{CO3} + \ce{4e-} \to \ce{C} + \ce{3O^2-}$ [and reduction of metal ions, along with oxidation of carbonate ions:] $\ce{2CO3^2-} \to \ce{2CO2} + \ce{O2} + \ce{4e-}$

**Sulfates**

*Polarization measurements on solid platinum-molten sodium sulphate-sodium chloride interfaces*, EIectrochimica Acta, Vol. 23, pp. 381-388, 1978:

> the limiting reactions [...] are suggested to be the $\ce{SO3}$ reduction to $\ce{S^2-}$ and $\ce{O2-}$ and the $\ce{SO4^2-}$ oxidation to $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$

Answer (score 1):

Carbonates will lose CO2 on melting and turn into oxides.

Nitrates usually decompose/blow up on melting. Electrolysis will speed up explosion. Before they blow up O2 will form. Water solutions at low temperatures can also form NO4$^-$ (pernitrates).

Sulfates will form O2. water solutions of sulfates also form persulfates at low temperature.

Comment: "Nitrate molten salts are extensively used for sensible heat storage in Concentrated Solar Power (CSP) plants and thermal energy storage (TES) systems." - D'Aguanno et al., Scientific Reports, 8, 10485 (2018)